# transform scale can't see side by side

Tags: css

hey how do i set the appropriate margin between elements when i use tranform: scale? Namely, when there is no "tranform: scale" property, the margins between elements are correct, and when I set @media screen and (min-width: 980px), I want to enlarge element2, but then it increases, and element1 and element3 do not move away o these 32px To illustrate, I am sending the code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.el1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.el2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 32px;
  background-color: green;
}

.el3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .el2 {
    transform: scale(1.6);
    margin: 0 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="el1">Element1</div>
  <div class="el2">Element2</div>
  <div class="el3">Element3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you are setting width and height to begin with, you might as well just set width and height again in media query. You can group the 3 divs or add another class so that you can define 1 rule for the size. `.el1, el2, .el3 { ... }` or `.extraClassName { ... }`

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: Scaling does not increase the space an element takes, just increase the width and height as needed instead of scaling

Comment: I can't because element2 is a picture

Comment: You can increase the size of an image, just like you did when setting the size of it